# Truncate name of all worksheets at "_" character

Tags: excel, vba

My workbook contains many different worksheets of different names at different lengths. I want to truncate all of the names of the worksheets at the "_" character. My code so far looks like this:

```
Sub LoopOverEachColumn()
     Dim WS As Worksheet    
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False

     For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            ReNme WS
     Next WS  
End Sub

Sub ReNme()
Dim Wsearch, Wlen As Integer
Dim Wname, Wnn As String

    Wname = WS.Name
    Wsearch = InStr(0, Wname, "_", 1)
    Wlen = Len(Wname)
    Wnn = Right(Wname, Wlen - WSsearch)
    WS.Name = Wnn

End Sub
```

It's breaking at InStr with object error 424 and I can't get InStr to work properly.

Comment: Can you write an example with name? If i understood your question you can use Split(Wname,"_")(0). With this row of code you get this: example, begin with this string Mysheet_example.xslx and you get this result Mysheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub LoopOverEachColumn()
     Dim WS As Worksheet

     For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
          WS.Name = Split(WS.Name, "_")(0)
     Next WS
End Sub
```